# How do i delete the blank rows this outputs when using python to write records to csv without over writing all records that exist in csv?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have been trying to remove the blank row from between the records in my csv file using python without wiping the whole spreadsheet.

```
import csv, os

def display(file):              # this procedure displays file and returns the last ID
    f=csv.reader(open(file,'r'))
    for i in f:
        ID = i[0]
        print i
    return ID

def newentry(file, rec):            # this writes the rec to the file
    f=csv.writer(open(file,'a'))
    f.writerow(rec)

#--------------------------------------
''' this is the main program that -
1. creates the next ID value
2. takes the inputs for record to be written
3. define the record in the correct order
'''

#---to append a new entry with the next value for ID

n = input("Enter number of records to add:")
for i in range(n):
    ID=int(display('records.csv'))+1
    fname=raw_input("Please enter the First Name:")
    sname=raw_input("Please enter the Surname:")
    hnumber=raw_input("Please enter the house name or number:")
    street=raw_input("Please enter the name of the street:")
    area=raw_input("Please enter the area:")
    county=raw_input("Please enter the County:")
    pcode=raw_input("Please enter the Postcode:")
    tel=raw_input("Please enter the contact number:")
    rec=(ID,fname,sname,hnumber,street,area,county,pcode,tel)
    newentry('records.csv', rec)


#---- to display the file for confirmation

display('records.csv')
```

This creates records like this:

```
1,dave,davidson,1,avenue,somewhere,somewhere,pppppp,0111111111

2,jeff,jefferson,3,street,overthere,overhere,tttttt,0222222222
```

but I need it to show in Excel like this:

```
1,dave,davidson,1,avenue,somewhere,somewhere,pppppp,0111111111
2,jeff,jefferson,3,street,overthere,overhere,tttttt,0222222222
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: For some reason I can't run your code. It says some variable was referenced before assignment. But I would suggest converting rec to string and then writing with `','.join([str(el) for el in rec])`.

Comment: The code runs fine for me but the empty line does not appear.

Comment: Are these blank lines in the original CSV file you are opening?  Make sure you are opening it with `'rb'` or `'wb'` for reading/writing to avoid the arbitrary extra line.

Comment: sounds like a cr/lf thing-- esp if the source file and code are mixing linux/mac/windows end of line conventions.

Comment: Are these blank lines in the original CSV file you are opening? Make sure you are opening it with 'rb' or 'wb' for reading/writing to avoid the arbitrary extra line. –  @paidhima using these wipes all information from my csv

Comment: @marein perhaps this may be an excel issue then?

Comment: just to state i am using Python on windows on a PC

Comment: The `'wb'` is a write flag and truncates the file before writing.  The `'rb'` is a read flag, so it won't wipe anything.  If you want to append, use `'ab'`.

Comment: @DamienCresswell Perhaps try opening the file once at the start of the script rather than each time `newentry` is called.